# Selecting lists of data and determining their place

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to determine whether the team is either home or away. In my code the team with ‘home’= 1 is the home team and 0 is away. As you can see below the code will select two teams from each game (home and away); however, it struggles to find out who is home and who is away! It has worked perfectly in finding the home and away team up until I reached the 6th game created in which it has mixed up home and away. Any ideas on how to fix this!

**game Table:**

[image]

**gameLink Table:**

[image: gameLink Table]

**SQL query:**

```
$gameQuery = "SELECT * FROM game, gameLink, teams WHERE gameLink.gameid = game.gameid AND gameLink.teamid = teams.teamid ORDER BY game.gameid";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($gameQuery);
        $stmt->execute();

        $gameList = array();
        $count = 0;         


        while($gD = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           $gameList[$count] = $gD;
            $count++; 
        }
```

**Printing teams into a table: (table tags are outside the PHP)**

```
for($index = 0; $index < count($gameList); $index+=2) {
    echo "<tr>
       <td>{$gameList[$index]['gameid']}</td>
       <td>{$gameList[$index]['name']}</td> 
       <td>{$gameList[$index+1]['name']}</td>
       <td><a href='games.php?editid={$gameList[$index]['gameid']}'<button class='btn btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button></a> <a href='games.php?deleteid={$gameList[$index]['gameid']}'<button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></a></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

**Please note:** if I am missing any bits of helpful information please let me know as I really want to understand why this is not working and hope to fix it!

Also if there are better ways to approach this, I am very open to it and will be very happy to cop constructive criticism where possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order the SQL statement by game_id ASC and home DESC you should always get the correct order.

```
$gameQuery = "SELECT * FROM game, gameLink, teams WHERE gameLink.gameid = game.gameid AND gameLink.teamid = teams.teamid ORDER BY game.gameid ASC, gameLink.home DESC";
```

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! Could you elaborate as to why this works? I am still a little confused! Thanks! :)

Comment: you are selecting 2 records of gameLink for each game. without the ordering you can not be certain about the ordering of the home and the away team. By sorting by game_id ascending and by home descending you will get them in the correct order

Comment: Perfect, appreciate your help very much! I will accept your answer when the system allows me to :)